# Run command on all open tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, console, command, screenshot

I want do run a command in Google Chrome on all open tabs.

The command i want to run is CAPTURE SCREENSHOT in the developer console.

For instance, I have 10 open tabs and want to get a screenshot of all 10 websites.

Is it possible?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this behavior using the **chrome console** specifically or are you looking for **any way** to _capture screenshots__ of each Chrome tabs?